# datatables with rowGrouping plugin aoColumns definitions fail

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, datatable

Ok so I am working on a table. And I am using rowGrouping on this particular table. To date I have had no serious problems with datatables until now.

I am rendering my table via php, and then when the DOM is loaded I am calling datatables on it. So it creates the table all fancy like. Which the fancy part works awesome and for the most part as expected. However. I want to hide columns via the `aoColumns` object, I want to disable sorting on others, and all else. Of which I can't seem to do. So I am not exactly sure what to do in this scenario

This is the JavaScript/datatable call I use with row grouping.

```
    var oTable = $('#orgListings').dataTable({
                            "bAutoWidth": true,
                            "bRetrieve": true,
                            "bPaginate": false,
                            "aoColumns":
                            [
                                { "bSortable": false },
                                { "bSortable": false },
                                { "bSortable": false },
                                { "bSortable": false },
                                { "bSortable": false },
                                { "bSortable": false },
                                { "bSortable": false },
                                { "bSortable": false },
                                { "bSortable": false }
                            ]
        }).rowGrouping({
                iGroupingColumnIndex: 1,
                sGroupingColumnSortDirection: "asc",
                iGroupingOrderByColumnIndex: 0,
                bExpandableGrouping: true, 
                bExpandSingleGroup: true,
                iExpandGroupOffset: -1
        });
        $('#orgListings_length, #orgListings_filter').hide()
        $(window).bind('resize', function(){oTable.fnDraw();});
```

My table is similar but not exactly to

```
<table>
  <thead>
     <tr>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
        <th></th>
     </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
     <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Again the row grouping seems to work properly. But anything within the `dataTable({...})` doesn't seem to stick. Pagination despite being false still shows, Auto width, despite being true doesn't stick turning all the columns into non sortable columns doesn't work.

So I am wondering what I am doing wrong? And how do I fix it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found out what my issue was.. Apparently the author of the template I bought "White Label" from themeforest.net used a bit of code
`$content.datatable({sPagination:"full_numbers"});`
in a globalized script.js. That was being ran on my tables before anything else was thus leaving anything I did custom in the `$.datatable` call useless on any table. I commented that bit out after finding it, and everything works as expected from datatables.

Thank you Todd Gibson, your suggestion was quite helpful at just adding a little bit of optimization to my overall code base, unfortunately it wasn't the fix for my initial problem, but you did help me in other ways.

Answer (score 1):

You probably want to do something like this:

```
var nonSortableColumns = new Array(0, 1, 2, 3);
```

Then

```
        "aoColumnDefs": [ 
            { "bSortable": false, "aTargets": nonSortableColumns }
        ],
```